# Open URL with external browser in Messenger

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm building a (Facebook) Messenger chatbot which needs to send a URL to the user which may be handled by a specific application instead of a web browser.

By default messenger opens URLs in a integrated web view instead of delegating the task of finding a suitable app to the OS.

I cannot force my users to change their Messenger settings to disable the web view, so what is a way of telling messenger not to try and open my link in its embedded web view?

The issue is not and Android one since intent filters are set up and working correctly. Messenger simply doesn't publish an intent when the URL is clicked, and only displays it in a web view.

Answer (score 0):

All URLs in FB Messenger open in their webview, but you can still use deeplinks to open a native app and launch a specific screen on the user's mobile device. That way, when the user clicks on a given URL / URL button, they will "switch" from the FB Messenger chatbot to an application on their mobile device.

To create a deeplink for your Android app, it seems that the Mobile Deeplinking Library highlighted on [this website](http://mobiledeeplinking.org/) (Section 2.3) will help. It lists instructions and details about how to set up your own deeplinks for iOS and Android applications.

I've only done a bit of research into mobile deeplinking but I hope this helps solve the problem!